# Spark - How to calculate percentiles in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to to get the 0.8 percentile of a single column dataframe. I tried in this way:

```
val limit80 = 0.8
val dfSize = df.count()
val perfentileIndex = dfSize*limit80 

dfSorted = df.sort()
val percentile80 = dfSorted .take(perfentileIndex).last()
```

But I think this will fail for big dataframes, since they may be distributed across different nodes.

Is there any better way to calculate the percentile? or how could I have all the rows of the dataframe in the same machine (even if that is very anti-pattern) so the `df.take(index)` will really take into account the whole dataset and not just a partition in a node.

Comment: you can use hive apis https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-aggregate-functions

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Spark 2.x, you can use [approxQuantile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions@approxQuantile(cols:Array[String],probabilities:Array[Double],relativeError:Double):Array[Array[Double]]), as in the following example:

```
val df = Seq(
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
).toDF("num")

df.stat.approxQuantile("num", Array(0.8), 0.1)
// res4: Array[Double] = Array(26.0)
```

Note that the smaller the 3rd parameter `relativeError`, the more expensive is the calculation.  Here's a relevant note in the API doc:

> **relativeError**: The relative target precision to achieve (greater than
>   or equal to 0).  If set to zero, the exact quantiles are computed,
>   which could be very expensive.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I was using Spark 1.6 and I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Spark SQL function `approx_percentile(col, percentage)`:

```
val df = Seq(0.5, 0.4, 0.1).toDF
df.agg(expr("approx_percentile(value, array(0.5))").as("percentile")).show
// +----------+
// |percentile|
// +----------+
// |     [0.4]|
// +----------+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile

Answer (score 3):

With large datasets, you probably should go with an approximate approach

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{callUDF, lit}

df.agg(callUDF("percentile_approx", $"someColumn", lit(0.8)).as("percentile80"))
```

Comment: this is actually a hive UDAF and rather slow

Comment: @RaphaelRoth out of curiosity, do you have more info about this?
Had a quick run comparing the two over a billion integer and with the same accuracy (0.0001), the UDF one is actually consistency faster in that particular case

Comment: i've made some benchmarks comparing hives `percentile` with a costum UDAF and with using `collect_list` followed by an UDF to calculate the percentiles, and hives `percentile` was the slowest option in my case.

Answer (score 2):

[approx_percentile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile) and [percentile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) are part of the SQL API.

Suppose you have the following DataFrame:

```
+--------+
|some_int|
+--------+
|       0|
|      10|
+--------+
```

Here's how to calculate the 50th percentile with the expr hack:

```scala
df.agg(expr("percentile(some_int, 0.5)").as("50_percentile"))
```

```
+-------------+
|50_percentile|
+-------------+
|          5.0|
+-------------+
```

I created a library called [bebe](https://github.com/MrPowers/bebe) that also exposes these methods via the Scala API (so you don't need to write strings that invoke functions in your Scala code).

```scala
df.agg(bebe_percentile(col("some_int"), lit(0.5)).as("50_percentile"))
```

```
+-------------+
|50_percentile|
+-------------+
|          5.0|
+-------------+
```

See the bebe README for instructions on how to use `bebe_approx_percentile`.